# Prove that the result of division by a number defined within a set by another number within that set, results in a number also in that set.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Say we defined a set like (for example):

$$\mathbb{S} = \{1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19,..., 3n+1,…\}$$

or more generally $$S = \{x | x = an + z\}$$ such that $$a,z \in \mathbb{Z}$$

My question is, is it possible to demonstrate (and is it even necessarily true?) That the division of a number in a set by another number in the same set, assuming that that division is possible without remainder, is also in that set?

So, let:

$$
b,c  \in \mathbb{S} \\
b > c \\
c \lvert b \\
d = \frac{b}{c}
$$
Is it then neccesarily true that ${d} \in \mathbb{S}$? How would I prove this property in general? And what/why would be the necessary properties of $\mathbb{S}$ for this to be true if it was not true in general.

Comment: $\frac{7}{4}$ isn't in that set.

Comment: A more useful description of your set is that an integer $x$ is in $S$ if and only if both: $x > 0$ and $x \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

Comment: One problem more strong is: $x\in S$ prove that $\exists y \in S$ such that $\frac{x}{y}\in S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your set consists of integers. If such a set meeting your requirements is possible then for any  $x,y$ in your set both  $\frac xy$ and $\frac yx$ should be integers: that is these numbers should be multiples of each other. $x$ multiple of $y$ means $x\geq y$ and we also need $y\geq x$; this forces $x=y$. So if your set has more than one element it is impossible.

You should allow your set to have rational numbers to make this possible. And it has to be infinite.

For example, the set $1,10,1/10,100,1/100,1000,1/1000, \ldots $. That is, for any fixed $n$,   ${n^k}$ for $k\in\mathbf{Z}$ would be such examples.
(In algebra it is called the multiplicative group generated by a single number $n$ with an unfortunate, but well-established, terminology *infinite cyclic* group, though nothing cycles back here. One can also similarly manufacture groups generated by more elements).

EDIT (after comment imposing extra condition):

If we are going to always divide the bigger integer by smaller integer, then one can expect  to find such a sets. Just modify my definition above restricting to just *non-negative powers*. Examples for such  sets are $\{1,6^1, 6^2, 6^3,6^{4},\ldots\}$ . The division gives always a non-negative power of $6$ again.

Comment: That's a wonderful answer! Unfortunately my question may have been insufficiently clear.

I meant: Assume x > y; and let y|x. Then x/y = z; z should be in the same set. Going to edit the question for clarification.

Comment: @AbrahamP: I've revised the answer, now.

Comment: Interesting. So then does that mean that in sets of the structure an +z (e.g. not necessarily powers), the property does not hold? e.g. there are some elements for which division by a smaller member of the set produces something outside the set?

Comment: In your example odd and even numbers alternate, so there will be odd numbers that are bigger than even ones, and the division will leave a remainder.

Comment: My apologies if my question was unclear. There is the condition that this only apply to numbers that divide without remainder (as specified, I thought) in the question. I would greatly appreciate if you could help me clarify the question!

Comment: Ok here is a counter example $\{10,40, 120,6000,70\}$.. Here we notice 40/10=4, 6000/120=50$ are missing in the set, though the divisions are possible without remainders.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the help!